# can we find an isomorphism between $R$ and $eR$ ,where $R$ is von Neumann regular ring and $e$ is idempotent of $R$?

Tags: ring-theory

In essay  i am reading, we have an finitely generated ideal, so it is generated by an idempotent element $e\in R$ (since finitely generated ideals generated by an idempotent element in von Neumann regular ring)

Then it is written that ''we can replace $eR$ by $R$''. I can't understand how and why. I am on the opinion that there should be isomorphism between $R$ and $eR$,but couldn't see yet. ($R$ is not domain)

Could anyone help me ?

Comment: Please take a look at my edits that introduce TeX markup (and whitespacing to make things more readable) and try to do that in future posts... it will benefit your questions greatly!

Comment: And apparently you are working with *commutative* VNR rings?

Comment: Really, there must be some more context near the phrase "we can replace $eR$ by $R$"... could you provide it? We've already resolved the question you originally asked, but now maybe we can work to resolve what the author means.

Comment: i am sorry about my writing mistakes.The ring that i study is not commutative,just VNR.Actually i have $n$ vectors from $R^{n}$,and sum of their contents equals $R$.So these sum equals eR, for some idempotent e.Then it says ''we can replace $eR$ by $R$,so sum of these content equals $R$''.There is nothing more.I quess it thinks homomorphism $eR$ to $R$ taking $e$r to $ r$.it is onto and one-to-one.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by content actually... could you define it?

Comment: $er\mapsto r$ is not a well defined map unless $e=1$. If $r\neq er $, then $er\mapsto r$ and $er=e(er)\mapsto er$ shows the map is not well defined.

Comment: Of course i try to explain what is content.If we are talking about vector $x$ in $R^{n}$ then content of  $x$,denoted by c(x),is an ideal of $R$ generated by coordinates of $x$.

Comment: ıf we are talking about matrix,similarly it is an ideal generated by entries of the matrix. or if we talk about submodule $M$ of $R^{n}$,content of $M$ is  the ideal generated by all vectors in $M$.

Comment: I see why the contents are a summands but I don't see any reason the leap in logic you are describing is appropriate. Maybe with even more context we could figure it out.

Comment: we have figured out it.It wasnt about ring homomorphisim ,just about idempotetnt property.Let me try to explain.Now suppose $x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}$ in $R^{n}$ and $c(x_{1})+c(x_{2)}+..+c(x_{n})=eR$ for some idempotent element $e$ of $R$.then multiply this equation by $e$.Since $eR=e^{2}R$,we reach that every element of the form $er_{i,j}x_{i,j}$ can b written as $r_{i,j}x_{i,j}$ ,so we are able to replace $eR$ and $R$

Answer (score 2):

No, not always.

Look at $R=F_2\times F_2$ where $F_2$ is the field of two elements.

$R$ is von Neumann regular and is clearly not isomorphic to $(1,0)R\cong F_2$.

But on the other hand, if $S=\prod_{i\in \mathbb N} F_2$, there exists a nontrivial idempotent $e$ such that $eS\cong S$ (and there exist other idempotents which do not satisfy that.)